# mysqli why does this happens?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two subsequent mysqli statements, and the second returns:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ...

Why this happens? Does this means that I need to open two different connection?
Is there any way to avoid this (I love keeping the SQL connection details in one file)?

Here the code:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database");

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE posts SET vote_".$_POST['vote']." = vote_".$_POST['vote']." + 1 WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['id_post']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO votes (kind, users_id, posts_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$_POST['vote'],$_POST['id_user'],$_POST['id_post']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I sure hope you're sanitizing those post inputs.

Comment: I thought that using mysqli would completely avoid sql injection?

Comment: If using bound values/parameters, you're safe from SQL injection. But what prevents the user from sending the user id of somebody else?

Comment: Several checks that happens way before those queries that are terminated with die()

Comment: @0plus1: It's important to note that it's not MySQLi that protects you from SQL injection (it's very easy to use MySQLi and still be vulnerable!), but the _prepared statements_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return value of [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php). If it is FALSE, you should get the details for the occured error with [mysqli::error](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php).

Answer (score 1):

I think your $stmt variable is null when you call bind_param over it. maybe your $_POST['vote'] is empty? you can check it before you bind the param on the command

Answer (score 0):

Something might have gone wrong with `$db->prepare()`, check `$db->error`.

Comment: That was the problem, I named differently one of the fields.. shame on me for not checking the error.. I thought that was a problem of making two consecutive queries.. thanks!