# Why do I get this function call error on an non-object when I am calling a function on an object?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

#### Error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
> bind_param() on a non-object in
> /var/www/web55/web/pdftest/events.php
> on line 76

#### Code:

```
public function countDaysWithoutEvents(){       
    $sql = "SELECT 7 - COUNT(*) AS NumDaysWithoutEvents
            FROM    
            (SELECT d.date 
                FROM cali_events e
                LEFT JOIN cali_dates d
                ON e.event_id = d.event_id
                WHERE YEARWEEK(d.date) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())
                AND c.category_id = ?
                GROUP BY DAY(d.date)
            ) AS UniqueDates";
            
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $this->locationID);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $stmt->bind_result($count);
    $stmt->close();
    
    return $count;
}
```

`$this->link->prepare($sql)` creates a prepared statement for MySQLi.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: try doing a var_dump($stmt) before the bind_param()

Comment: On a different note, the bind_param() should have 1 as its first parameter.

Comment: @Flavius: No, it should have the type as the first parameter as documented here: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object), [mysqli why does this happens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725679/)...

Comment: @pal4life, they're not similar except in the title and technology use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND c.category_id = ?` - there is no table alias c in your query.

Besides that try

```
$stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
if (!$stmt) {
  throw new ErrorException($this->link->error, $this->link->errno);
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param('i', $this->locationID) || !$stmt->execute()) {
  throw new ErrorException($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
}
```

Comment: +1: I didn't notice c was missing when I read through it.  Whoops.

Comment: The query has a certain "smell" anyway, at least it _seems_ suboptimal if not wrong ;-)

Comment: AH! Duh! It should be e.category_id. *headdesk*

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is obviously with the **prepare** function..

The function is probably failing, in which case $stmt would be FALSE and hence not have the bind_param method as a member.

> From the [php mysqli manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):
>   mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

Check your query!  Maybe there is a problem with your SELECT statement. And also check for FALSE before trying to execute any member function on what you think is an object returned by the prepare function.

```
if($stmt === FALSE)
    die("Prepare failed... ");// Handle Error Here

// Normal flow resumes here
$stmt->bind_param("i","");
```

**EDIT**

I would suspect that the statement may be erroring out because of the sub-query:

```
SELECT d.date 
 FROM cali_events e
 LEFT JOIN cali_dates d
 ON e.event_id = d.event_id
 WHERE YEARWEEK(d.date) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())
 AND c.category_id = ?
 GROUP BY DAY(d.date)
```

Instead, why don't you write your query like this:

```
public function countDaysWithoutEvents()
{
    $count = FALSE;

    $sql  = "SELECT COUNT(d.date) ";
    $sql .= " FROM cali_events e ";
    $sql .= "      LEFT JOIN cali_dates d ON e.event_id = d.event_id ";
    $sql .= " WHERE YEARWEEK(d.date) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) ";
    $sql .= "       AND c.category_id = ? ";
    $sql .= " GROUP BY DAY(d.date) ";

    $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt !== FALSE)
    {                
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $this->locationID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($count);
        $stmt->fetch();                    // I think you need to do a fetch
                                           // here to get the result data..
        $stmt->close();
    }else                                  // Or, provide your own error
        die("Error preparing Statement");  // handling here

    return (7 - $count);
}
```

*P.S. I think you also had a missing a call to **fetch** as well..* (see example above)

Comment: but the query executes fine in the console

Comment: well, that may be, but that doesn't mean that MySQLi can't complain about something. I know there are some limitations with executing MySQL code from PHP mostly for preventing SQL injection.. mostly regarding subqueries..

Comment: how can I correct it, that sub query really needs to be there.

Comment: no, they query returns an inaccurate result. I'm counting the number of days that do not have events attached to them.

Answer (score 0):

$this->link->prepare this statement is not returning the object
so it is giving you the error